# How to run a command in terminal and capture the output

Tags: c#, linux, monodevelop

I am working on an application using `MonoDevelop` in `Ubuntu`. Through this application I need to run a terminal command and capture it's output. Is such thing possible? Any help/ideas will be appreciated!

What I mean is, if user clicks on a button, the command will be run and the output will be displayed in a text box or something. I don't want a terminal window pop-up, this action should be entirely done inside the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# Windows you would do this:

```
Process p = new Process(); // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "program.exe"; 
p.Start();  // Do not wait for the child process to exit before reading to the end of its     redirected stream.
p.WaitForExit(); // Read the output stream first and then wait.
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Process implements IDisposable, It is best to not leave it hanging around like this ;)

Comment: That was actually taken from a Microsoft example :)